# Wifi is not detected

Tags: wireless

I just installed a fresh copy of ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I am having problems with the wifi. I went into additional drivers and enabled Broadcom and applied it but, even after I restart my laptop it still wont show any wifi in my internet connections. ANyway to fix this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers